# Hotot Direct Messaging Issue

Tags: twitter, hotot

Everytime I DM (direct message), it gets posted in the public timeline as well. Is there a solution? I'm using hotot 0.9.6.

Comment: Hello, I am the developer of Hotot. 

I can not reproduce this problem. Can you describe more details?

Comment: @shellex http://code.google.com/p/hotot/issues/detail?id=334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a bug report. Please file a [bug report here](http://code.google.com/p/hotot/issues/list) with the Hotot project.

Comment: done...http://code.google.com/p/hotot/issues/detail?id=334

Comment: @Amith Viswanath Awesome. I've encountered this as well, I'm just too lazy to file a bug report with them. Marking as "Affecting me" as well.

Comment: that's my first bug report ever!wish they will rectify it soon

Comment: Welcome to the club of being a bug reporter! :) And same here. It's a major enough issue that it needs to be handled ASAP.

Comment: i ♥ this site...I used to tweet for help..but didnt get any replies..this is great!!!